# Image And Text Glitch In Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I couldn't give a good look to the text [here](https://www.graspdating.com/tao1/), wordpress doesn't allow me to do that.

[image: Check this image N1]

[image: Check this image N2]

Comment: How can we know this without you posting some HTML and CSS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your alignment styles for the front-end.

You should try adding the following into your theme's style.css file and refresh the cache to see the change.

```
.alignleft,
img.alignleft {
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}

.alignright,
img.alignright {
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

.aligncenter,
img.aligncenter {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I just did, I think the editor still doesnt allow me to place two lines of text  beside the image

Comment: Once you've done this. Refresh the page in the front-end. There are no options that change in the back-end.

Comment: I did that too, you could check it yourself and let me know what's going on

Comment: Your IMG class says `alignnone`. Please, be sure you've aligned this to the right via the editor or using `alignright`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see what you mean

Comment: Click Text in your editor and put in `<img class="alignright" src="your-image-url.jpg" />`

Comment: Sorry, I got it

Comment: Thank's for saving my life man :) 
Check this out https://image.ibb.co/hBziOz/image.png
May I know what controls this space?

Comment: I really couldn't figure it out